# Bootstrap alert div

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

In my project for login error I used the bootstrap alert. But the problem is that when there is an error it displaying well. But if there is not an error it show an empty box can anyone tell me what the problem?
At starting I don't want to show this empty div. can anyone tell me how to hide this and show this div when there is an error?

***The screen is***

[image]

***If there is an error output screen works***
[image]

***Code is***

```
<script>
 window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
}, 4000);
</script>
<!-- Below Alert div Start -->
      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" id="alert" role="alert">
        {update_message}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
<!-- Below Alert div End -->
```

***html code***

```
{HEADER_HTML} {HEADER_MIDDLE_HTML}
<script>
  function placeHolderAdd() {
  const mailInput1 = document.querySelector("[name='TREF_email_address1']").placeholder = "enter email";
  const passwordInput1 = document.querySelector("[name='TR_password1']").placeholder = "enter password";
  const mailInput2 = document.querySelector("[name='TREF_email_address2']").placeholder = "enter email";
  const passwordInput2 = document.querySelector("[name='TR_password2']").placeholder = "enter password";
}
window.addEventListener('load', placeHolderAdd);
</script>
<!-- Below Script for auto close -->
<!-- <script>
 window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
}, 4000);
</script> -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  const alertText = document.querySelector(".alert-content");
  if (alertText.value = "") {
    console.log('null')
  }
</script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">

      <!-- Below Alert div Start -->
      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" id="myAlert" role="alert">
        <div class="alert-content">
          <!-- {update_message} -->
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Below Alert div End -->

      <div class="card card-custom">
        <div class="card-header card-header-custom">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">
                <i class="fa fa-user loginicon" aria-hidden="true"></i> {HEADING_TITLE1}
                
                
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">
                <i class="fa fa-briefcase loginicon" aria-hidden="true"></i> {HEADING_TITLE2}
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>  
        
        <div class="card-body card-body-custom">
          
          <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
              <h5 class="ml-3 pb-2">{SIGN_IN}</h5>
              <div>{AREA1}</div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
              <h5 class="ml-3 pb-2">{SIGN_IN}</h5>
              <div>{AREA2}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


{FOOTER_HTML}
```

Comment: you can see your error solution is hear in this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/alerts/#dismissing

Comment: @bhumin alert dismiss is working. I do not want this blank div...

Answer (score 1):

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if ($('.alert-content').text().trim() == "") {
                $(".alert").hide();
            } else {
                $(".alert").show();
            }
        });
```

```css
  .alert{

     background:#eee
  
  }
  
  .alert *{
  
     display:inline
  
  }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" id="alert" role="alert">
        <div class="alert-content">
            
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

First of all put text inside a `div`

```
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" id="alert" role="alert">
    <div class="alert-content">
        {update_message}
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

Now you can check if message is empty with JQuery (I'm checking on document ready)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.alert-content').text().trim() == "") {
        $(".alert").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".alert").show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I used your code but nothing is working. still same blank div appears.

Comment: it is called from .php file and this code is in .html file

Comment: Ok, the code should work if your `{update_message}` is completly empty. However, when your document is ready maybe your `{update_message}` has not been set yet. In this case use a `setTimeout()` or some other trigger

Comment: I've added a snippet, as you can see the alert is hidden

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code.

 hear is `javascript` code:

```
<script>
        
        $(function(){
          $(".close").on("click",function(){
            $(".alert").hide();
          });
           window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                $(this).hide(); 
            });
        }, 4000);
        })
</script>
```

Hear is 'HTML' code:

```
<!-- Below Alert div Start -->
      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" id="alert" role="alert">
        {update_message}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

I saw your code I don't see any button which clicks event remove that alert box so You can see some examples for your requirements.
[How to make alert button hide show using jquery, bootstrap on button click event.](http://one7techlab.com/post/how-to-make-alert-button-hide-show-using-jquery-bootstrap-on-button-click-event-4)

Comment: not working...basically at starting I doesn't want this blank div. If there is an error while user submit the form then alert div appear and disclose. But Now in this case now form submit but alert div persist.

Comment: ok, can you share the code of your form. I have to check to submit button click event code.

Comment: full html code is added...but I tell you these `{ name_whatever }` is called from .php file. And under .php code is not written by me I'm trying to fixing the login alert message.

Comment: yes, I understand that because i am a PHP web developer and also my expertise in PHP  laravel framework.

Comment: But this is core php....and my expertise also in Laravel framework :)

Comment: ok no problem more than 2 years experience in code both PHP and laravel framework

Comment: Can I apply some condition in script tag if there is not text or whatever or if an error someting....?

Comment: I can not see any submit button in your whole code but I found the solution to your problem you can also make a hide using the login button click event. first put login button and try this code : http://one7techlab.com/post/how-to-make-alert-button-hide-show-using-jquery-bootstrap-on-button-click-event-4

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just need to make it so that if there is an error with the login, depending on how that works, it might be a query in the URL stating what error it is, show the whole modal.

Currently what is happening is that your modal is showing with nothing in it as there is no error.

So you need to make it so that the whole modal is only shown once there is an error.

I hope this helps with anyone else trying to help, it seems that a lot of people were misunderstanding what is going on here.

Comment: yes, if there is an error then the div appear, but in my case if there is no error.empty div appear or if there is an error, correct div appear with message.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying, the div needs to be hidden when there is no error.

Comment: do you have any idea how to hide and unhide if errror occur?

Comment: Well I'm not really sure how your application works. You mentioned it uses PHP but you posted a html code block?

Comment: basically {update_message} variable called from php file

Comment: What if you made the whole modal a variable in the PHP file, and then in the PHP file it can change the modal's message based on the error it has

Comment: I solve the problem I have put this div under php file code.